# Recursive definition in kernel of a morphism.

Tags: category-theory

I find the following definition in *Serge* *Lang*'s Algebra on p 133:

> Given a morphism $f:E\rightarrow F$ in an additive category, we define a **kernel** of $f$ to be a morphism $E'\rightarrow E$ such that for all objects $X$ in the category, the following sequence is exact:
>   $0\rightarrow Mor(X,E')\rightarrow Mor(X,E)\rightarrow Mor(X,F).$

This definition is extremely strange, exact sequence is defined only when kernel is defined, but this definition is to define kernel, how can it use kernel to define kernel?

Comment: The objects in the sequence are abelian groups, not objects in the original category. So we already know what exact sequences are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $0\rightarrow Mor(X,E')\rightarrow Mor(X,E)\rightarrow Mor(X,F)$ consists of of abelian groups, not of objects in the original category.  So Lang is referring to the ordinary definition of exactness of sequences of maps of abelian groups.

Comment: What are the group homorphisms of those arrows?

Comment: They are the homomorphisms given by composition with the maps $E'\to E$ and $E\to F$.  For instance, the map $Mor(X,E)\to Mor(X,F)$ takes a map $X\to E$ and sends it to the map $X\to F$ obtained by composing with $f$.